# Airflow marks DAG as successful even though the inner task returns error

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

So I have a DAG which uses BashOperator to trigger a spark job on our server. The spark job reads the data from S3 bucket which is segregated into day wise partitions and performs actions, if there is no data in the bucket it returns a 'path does not exits' error which is if there is no data in the bucket. But what is happening is that the spark returns an exception with logLevel of ERROR but airflow prints the logs with INFO level. And thus even if there is an error in the task, Airflow marks it as success run.

The logs are as here:

> 

```
[2022-11-17, 08:46:37 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-11-17, 08:46:37 IST [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST [main] ERROR com.newjs.preprocessors.DeletedProfileContactsEligibleForRetPreProcessor - Error in Incremental Data Preprocessor
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist;
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:558)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:644)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:643)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.utils.ReadUtils.readParquetFromS3(ReadUtils.java:24)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.newjs.preprocessors.DeletedProfileContactsEligibleForRetPreProcessor.incrementalDataProcess(DeletedProfileContactsEligibleForRetPreProcessor.java:91)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.process(JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.java:91)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.main(JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.java:32)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist;
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:558)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:644)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:643)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.utils.ReadUtils.readParquetFromS3(ReadUtils.java:24)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.newjs.preprocessors.DeletedProfileContactsEligibleForRetPreProcessor.incrementalDataProcess(DeletedProfileContactsEligibleForRetPreProcessor.java:91)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.process(JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.java:91)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at com.js.JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.main(JsETLSparkTransformationsApplication.java:32)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
[2022-11-17, 08:46:41 IST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried to look for any setting where we can configure how Airflow logs the logs of the task but couldnt find any. Please comment if any additional info is required.Any kind of support would be helpful. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a spark job using `spark-submit`, it print the log coming from spark with different levels (INFO, WARN, ERROR,...) but when the spark job fail, the command `spark-submit` doesn't fail, it exit always with return value 0, so the task of your `BashOperator` doesn't fail then.

You can check the [official spark operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark/stable/operators.html) provided by Airflow community, it can solve your problem. And you can create a new operator which submit the job, parse the log to get the submit id, then use `spark-submit --status [submission ID]` to get the job state in order to fail when it fails.

Comment: There are a many a number of spark jobs run inside the for loop in the script, hence we cannot adopt this option. Is there any other way where we can parse the logs and trigger any alert according to whats inside them?